# How to make a sum of array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I iterate through its first 7 values with this function:

```
function clicksLast7Days($data)
        {
            $path = $data->data->data->clicks;
            $num_loops = 0;
            foreach ($path as $key => $item){
                $num_loops++;
                if($num_loops > 7) break;
                if ($key >= 0) {
                $array[] = $item->clicks;
                }     
            }
           return json_encode($array);   
        }
```

The array's structure (if it helps) is:

```
["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (3) {
    ["status_code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["data"]=>
    object(stdClass)#211 (3) {
      ["days"]=>
      int(30)
      ["total_clicks"]=>
      int(6)
      ["clicks"]=>
      array(30) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466395200)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#216 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466308800)
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#217 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466222400)
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#218 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466136000)
        }
        [4]=>
        object(stdClass)#219 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466049600)
        }
        [5]=>
        object(stdClass)#220 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1465963200)
        }
        [6]=>
        object(stdClass)#221 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1465876800)
        }
        [7]=>
        object(stdClass)#222 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1465790400)
        }
```

The problem is that by using my function I get an array of elements: 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. But what I want is to obtain their sum (which in this case is 0), and not an array, just a number.

Comment: before loop `$sum = 0;` in loop  `$sum += $item->clicks;`

Comment: If you want to calculate the sum, then why putting the values in an array? Why not using +=?

Comment: thank you splash58, this helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$clicksArray = $data->data->data->clicks;
$sum = array_sum(
    array_map(
        $clicksArray, 
        function($clickElement) {
            return $clickElement->clicks;
        }
    )
);
```

### What does this mean ?

- `array_sum` will sum all values of a certain array. More information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)
- `array_map` will return all elements of an array, after applying a function (so, basically here, we are returning only `clicks` attribute

Comment: `array_reduce` would serve here well, too